# Visual Studio ASP.Net expand and collapse issue in ashx generic handlers

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ashx

I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional and I am having issues with expanding and collapsing method code blocks in ASP.Net Generic Handler pages (.ashx)

I would have thought you could do the same thing like in the code behind of .aspx web pages.

I have this same issue on other boxes even with VS 2008 Standard and VS 2005 Professional.  All boxes have been fully patched (OS and Visual Studio.)

Does anybody have any suggestions as to enabling this feature?

Comment: Great question.  I hope someone else can come up with a better answer, though.  My annoyance is that when editing ASHX files, the code indentation preferences for HTML are used instead of the C# settings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can force Visual Studio to ignore the fact that it's code in front you're working with by going to:

Tools | Options

And opening the "Text Editor | File Extensions" tab.

Create a new entry for extension "ashx", mapped to editor "Microsoft Visual C#" (or "Microsoft Visual Basic", as your preference takes you), and "Add" it.

OK the dialog, close and re-open your ashx file, and your code blocks willl collapse to your hearts content, but the @ directive will be rather ugly.

You have the same issue if you have serverside script in the .aspx file (for example in a web site project and you don't "Place code in a seperate file"), then you cannot collapse the class blocks in there either.

Comment: And afterwards, to stop visual studio's whining about the `WebHandler` directive, just comment out the line, it will work as if it's not!

Comment: this absolutely fixes the outlining, but unfortunately breaks intellisense

Comment: It fixed intellisense at my machine (vs2012)

Comment: this will cause your code to be like incorrect, vs will higlight as red a lot of your liines of code. Useless

Comment: @Devmyselz I assume you're not still using VS 2008? I'd recommend using [bigEsmurf's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741158/33051) to move to a code-behind solution and have full integration that way.

Comment: I'm, using vs2015

Comment: I'd still suggest bigEsmurf's solution now.

Answer (score 12):

Create a class in the `App_Code` directory, which the ashx-file just references... like this:

SomethingHandler.ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SomethingHandler" %>
```

And in the `App_Code` folder I've created the file `SomethingHandler.cs` with class `SomethingHandler`

```
using System;
using System.Web;
// using blabla...

public class SomethingHandler : IHttpHandler
{
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext c)
        {
    etc...
```

Now I can just open SomethingHandler.cs, edit my C# code with #region collapsing, because the .cs file is opened in the right editor :)

[@ WebHandler docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms366713(v=vs.100))

Tested in VS 2019.

Comment: That's a very neat little solution :)

Comment: AWESOME solution <3

Comment: This also allows us to start using Refactor.Rename in handler code!

Answer (score 8):

Just select a fragment of code, like:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

Then Press "**Ctrl+M+H**" and Vualá... The Outlining Working Now... And Intellisense Too...

To Stop Outlining Press "**Ctrl+M+P**"...

Comment: This is the most practice solution that i found.

Comment: You are a rockstar. Ty.

Answer (score 6):

Add /// in front of first line.

Like this:

```
///<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FooBar"%>
```

Comment: This only will work if you add extension "ashx" mapped to editor "Microsoft Visual C#" at "Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extensions" tab.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix that won't interfere with IntelliSense or require you to edit the first line is to disable 'smart' indenting and set it to 'block' instead:

[image: Tools -> Options in Visual Studio]