# Generic Handlers (.ashx) intellisense issue on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to expand and collapse methods and other things on an ashx file like any other code behind file. When I do `tools > options > text editor and adding ashx as an extention of visual studio c#`, everything seems ok at the beginning. I can expand and collapse the methods also see the properties and methods at the top of the file. But then I lost most of intellisense. I cant reach my userdefined objects and methods.

**Similar Issues that I have found did not help me to solve this problem**

[Visual Studio ASP.Net expand and collapse issue in ashx generic handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359528/visual-studio-asp-net-expand-and-collapse-issue-in-ashx-generic-handlers)

[i can't add #region to .ashx in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310631/i-cant-add-region-to-ashx-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 3):

Ran in to this same annoyance.
To take @brichins solution/[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741158/592665) a little further, 
instead of using inheritance in your ashx just reference the class in the AppCode folder directly.

the ashx file would *only* contain the following

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyHandler" %>
```

Then create that class/MyHandler.cs file in the AppCode folder

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Use namespaces to avoid class name conflicts if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741158/957950) (to the first question you mentioned, but posted after you asked) seems to be the best option for me.

To summarize: create a separate class in a (preferably dedicated) .cs file to use as "code-behind", do all the work there (including implementing `IHttpHandler`) and have your actual handler in the .ashx just inherit it without doing anything else:

> public class MyHandler : MyIHttpHandlerCodeBehindClass{}

This gives you full code-folding and IntelliSense for your handler class without the issues you mentioned. Only downside is an additional file, but to me it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed most of my ashx to aspx, just so it can have CodeFile (separate .cs file).

Comment: ASPX could call masterpages and it has additional overhead which is not wanted...